# How to send data to custom button in laravel voyager admin panel

Tags: laravel, admin, voyager

I'm new to laravel and trying voyager admin panel .
I'm adding a custom button in voyager to assign a vendor to every orders . 
When admin clicks on custom button, it should send a order id to that new page .
I tried to send a value, but it's not working .
Any helps appreciated .

```
namespace App\Actions;

use TCG\Voyager\Actions\AbstractAction;

class MyAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return 'Assign to vendor';
    }

    public function getIcon()
    {
        return 'voyager-eye';
    }

    public function getPolicy()
    {
        return 'read';
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return [
            'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right',
        ];
    }


    public function shouldActionDisplayOnDataType()
    {
        return $this->dataType->slug == 'orders';
    }
    public function getDefaultRoute()
    {
        return route('vendors');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just pass the `id` of data collection

```php
public function getDefaultRoute()
{
    return route('vendors', $this->data->id);
}
```